# Which data does the requests.get function send to an API?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I have a very basic question about the request function in Python.
I'm making a requests.get to an external API from a corporate network.
I have specified the proxy(user:pw@address:port) and the verify(path to certificate). Unfortunately, this leads to an SSL error caused by the firewall. 
Now I have asked my colleague from the IT department for the setting verify = False. In this case the requests work and I get my result. Since I don't send/receive sensitive data, I don't really mind a security flaw. (purely theoretical)
My concerns relate more to the proxy data I provided. Since they have my personal ID and PW, I want to be sure that these data do not leave the company network, but are only used for proxy authentication.

How does the requests.get function work and what information does it send to the final API? Is proxy authentication also sent to the final API or is it just for the corporate network proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**
The `proxies` data is not part of the request that is sent to the remote server.

---

> How does the `requests.get` function work ...

`requests` conveniently wraps lower-level libs. Internally, it uses [`urllib3`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which uses [`http.client`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#module-http.client), which uses [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html). It's all about sending and receiving bytes via a network socket.

Ultimately, `requests` creates a [`PreparedRequest`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.PreparedRequest) object. This request object, resp. the data in its attributes, is sent down an INET socket, that is managed by an `urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection`, a class derived from `http.client.HTTPConnection`. This connection is managed by an `urllib3.connectionpool.ConnectionPool`, that is controlled by an `urllib3.poolmanager.Poolmanager`, which is part of a `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter`. This `HTTPAdapter` is referenced in a `requests.sessions.Session`, that is created and used by `requests.api.get()` through `requests.api.request()`.

> ... and what information does it send to the final API?

The parameters provided in the call to `requests.get` are used to create the request you want to send and/or for the connection that this request is sent through.

Parameters that end up in the request are: `method`, `url`, `headers`, `files`, `data`, `json`, `params`, `auth` and `cookies`.
Parameters, such as `verify`, `timeout` or `proxies` are solely used to establish and manage connections and do not show up in the request.

To show what is sent, here's a small, stupid and totally unfit for anything remote socket endpoint:

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('', 42424))
    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print(data.decode())
```

And our client:

```
import requests

params = {'foo': 'bar'}
requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:42424", params=params)
```

The 'server' prints:

```
GET /?foo=bar HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:42424
User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
```

Putting a very simple proxy between those two ...

```
from socketserver import ThreadingTCPServer
import urllib.request
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

class Proxy(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.copyfile(urllib.request.urlopen(self.path), self.wfile)

httpd = ThreadingTCPServer(('', 42425), Proxy)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

(This recipe was blatantly stolen (and adjusted for Python 3) from Fredrik Lundh at [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/librarybook/simplehttpserver.htm))

... and using `proxies` on the `requests.get` call ...

```
params = {'foo': 'bar'}
proxies = {'http': '127.0.0.1:42425'}
requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:42424", params=params, proxies=proxies)
```

... leads to the following being received by the 'server':

```
GET /?foo=bar HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: 127.0.0.1:42424
User-Agent: Python-urllib/3.6
Connection: close
```

So, credentials provided in `proxies` are kept between the proxy and your client.

Comment: Thank you very much for that detailed answer. That was exactly what I was looking for. Most important for me is that parameters are used to establish the connection and should not be sent via the API.